# Rails where condition with nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have `Delivery` model which has one `Postman` and that `Postman`has many `Team`s.

I would like to get all deliveries with specific team ID = 1 for example.

I have try:

```
Delivery.joins(:postman).where(:postmans => {team_ids: 1})
```

But I couldn't manage to get them. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do like below

```
Delivery.joins(:postman => :teams).where(:postman => {teams: {id: 1}})
```